# slider not aligned and breaks as copied to a new body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a slider :

I am trying to include this slider for the entire page in my site,right at the top .

But this is what I have been able to achieve : http://79.170.44.117/userprofile.

Please help me rectify the mistake.

Code in case the link doesnot work in future :

```html
<body>
   <div class="rotate-slider">
   <ul class="slides">
  <li>
    <div class="inner">
   <h2>Actual Rotating Slider</h2>
   <p>Built with math and dedication</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="inner">
   <h2>Hates IE</h2>
   <p>Uses clip-path to shape slides</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="inner">
   <h2>Easy to use</h2>
   <p>Just add list elements in the HTML and set a height and width in the JavaScript Settings</p>
   <p><small>Slider controls and proper jQuery plugin coming soon.</small></p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="inner">
   <h2>I'm not a thief!</h2>
   <p>Stock photos from www.pexels.com</p>
    </div>
  </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <svg>
  <defs>
   <clipPath id="slideClip">
   <path />
   </clipPath>
  </defs>
 </svg>
  

  
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]Just add this : Your bootstrap is overriding the classes

```
.slides li {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Or : At line 32 of slider.css

```
.rotate-slider ul.slides li{
     box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .u a genius.God bless.

Comment: Not a problem.. :)

Comment: You mean middle of the circle? Or center of the page? Coz they both are different positions.

Comment: For `.slider h1{bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;}`

Comment: I mean in the middle ,such that the slider slides around the text "Welcome" @Deepak

Comment: For `.slider{ position: relative }`